# Referencing an imported module from an App (Licensing LVL)

Tags: android, android-lvl, android-module

I followed the instructions how to setup licensing for an Android App and I am stuck in referencing the imported module.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#download-lvl

See on my screen, that I have imported the module into my App-project -> "lvlLibrary".

How can I reference the library from my Apps project ?

Project Structure:
[image]

My gradle (app):

```
dependencies {
//    compile project(':lvlLibrary') <- I TRIED THIS, BUT IT DOESN'T WORK.
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it:
adding

```
implementation project(':lvlproject')
compile project(path: ':lvlproject')
```

to gradle (app) did the trick.